# Different Joomla .gitignore files in different repos

Tags: git, joomla, github, gitignore

I am trying to use .gitignore file for my Joomla repo. I have noticed that the official joomla .gitignore file is much shorter as compared to the .gitignore provided by Github, which has an exhaustive list. Not sure why they are different.

This is joomla's .gitignore file: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/.gitignore

This is from github: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Joomla.gitignore

Was that intentional or is there a reason behind that?

My other question is what is the best practice to use .gitignore in my repo? Do I pull it from the remote repo or do I manually create a .gitignore file in my local repo?

Answer (score 5):

The difference is in the goal of the ignoring. I'll explain the two types of logic behind them. You'll have to decide what your goal is and then adjust your gitignore correctly.

Joomla's gitignore is built to ignore things that shouldn't go back into the distribution of Joomla: temporary files, cache files, and build files. Things that the system generates, but that you would never send to a friend.

Github builds a gitignore meant to ignore all of Joomla's core files. Thus, you would only see files for things like custom components that you add, custom templates, and other extensions or images that are added. This is meant to ignore Joomla, basically.

The question for you is "What is the point of your repo?". If you are managing a website built on Joomla, I would stick to Joomla's. If you are building a custom component or extension, you may prefer Github's. You may even want to do something completely different.

Just remember that any file in the gitignore will not be pushed up to the remote server, so it is completely ignored. Thus if someone else were to clone the repo, they would not see ignored files.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes I am building a module. So Github's .gitignore suits me better.